# How to handle backend and frontend code in a single repository when developing software

Tags: git, frontend, repository, backend

Recently I got a situation I would like to ask for best practices and advice, I'm a junior developer working with node and express for backend and react for frontend.
I have a single git repository with two folders one named Backend that contains all my server side logic and one called Frontend that contains my UI in react.
In the repository I have a branch called "Back" where I make all my commits related only with backend and another branch called "Front" where all the commits refer to the frontend. Here is the proccess for developing either in the backend or frontend:

1. Checkout to "Back" (changes in backend for example"
2. Make changes and commit to branch "Back"
3. Checkout to "Front" (changes in Frontend for example"
4. Make changes and commit to branch "Front"

The issue I'm having is the developing proccess, to run my code and make corrections I have to merge from "Back" to "Front" and viceversa so I have the most updated code in either branch and can run the backend server and frontend react app at the same time.

Another approach I've taken is having a "middle" branch so the "back" and "front" branches are merged to this one, then I can run the code because middle branch is the most updated, but this means I have to merged every little changes to middle branch in order to test the code.

I've seen some comments about separating the frontend and backend into their corresponding repositories but that doesn't seem right to me.

I've even heard about copying the repository into another folder and running my frontend from this "copy" repository on the "Front" branch, and runnning my backend code from the original folder so I can make changes without having to commit. This seems good but I see two issues, I have to duplicate the folders which means more disk space usage, and If I want to keep my repository up to date I have to push changes from my "copy" folder.

The last one I saw was having the backend into a folder, the frontend into another folder, each with its corresponding repositories in git and making on of the folders a "remote" locally allocated repository so I can run code at the same time, but again, I would need to pull the "Back" branch for example from the "remote local" repository and then I would have to push changes to github for example.

In conclusion, the question is: How in a professional environment is this issue handled? or what are the recommended practices to solve this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you can combine both repos into a single repo and then use branching strategy. Almost all of my friends use this strategy. It is working well.

Create these branches:

- **Master (or Main) branch**: This branch is important and used in production, which means not everybody can merge their changes. There should be 2-3 approvals (it depends on you) before merging Pull Requests.
- **Develop branch**: If you are working in agile systems like scrum, you and your team has a certain time period to achieve a sprint goal. For example a new feature in your website. Then all the changes made in this sprint (let's say one month) are merged into develop. At initial state, you can create develop from master and they are at the same level.
- **Release branch**: After your sprint goal is achieved, you can create a release branch from develop branch. Because you have all the new features in develop branch. Now release and develop are on the same level.

After you release your new version with release branch. you should merge it into master so that master should stay fresh like on production. After release you should tag your release branch and you can delete it. This is just for release purpose.

- **Feature branch**: This branch is mostly used branch. Let's say you and your team started the sprint with your new tickets. Each ticket corresponds a feature branch. Let's say adding a button. Then create your branch feature-adding-new-button. After you are done with your button, you can merge it into develop (if it is also tested beforehand). After that you can delete this branch.

**All in all if I try to depict it:**

- You have your one repo and one branch (**master** or main).
- Initially you create **develop from master**.
- Your sprint (or developing process starts)
- You create a feature branch from develop
- **(feature-add-a-button) <- develop**
- You make your changes and test it
- Then merge feature-add-a-button into develop
- **(feature-add-a-button) -> develop**
- Make another feature branch from develop (feature-add-image)
- **(feature-add-image) <- develop**
- You make your changes and test it.
- Then merge feature-add-image into develop
- **(feature-add-image) -> develop**
- Until here you have two new features on develop and master is behind.
- Now you want to release it.
- Create a (release-2-new-features) branch from develop.
- **(release-2-new-features) <- develop**
- Release it to production. Tag the release branch.
- After your release, merge it into master.
- **(release-2-new-features) -> master**
- Now you have develop, release and master at the same level.
- Delete release branch if you do not need it.

There is another important branch. Hotfix branch.
If you forgot something to release with release branch. You can create a hotfix branch from develop and add your bugfix, deploy it to production at this point and after that you can merge it back to develop and master. So in the end they are the same before you start your sprint.

[medium.com-Git branching strategies](https://medium.com/@selvamraju007/git-branching-strategies-a6eafe4541ae)

Comment: IMHO, this is a very detailed and useful answer! I would suggest though, that hotfix should probably branch out of master branch and then merged to both master and develop.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this case from two aspects:

- Branching strategy

You don't have to create separate back or front branches; instead, you can create feature branches based on your needs. A feature branch can include modifications for both the front-end and back-end, and the commits in this branch can correspond to both front-end and back-end code changes.

- Different development directories

If you want to keep your branching strategy, you can checkout the project twice in different directories and use different IDEs or separate windows to develop them. You can ignore the directory of the other project in your IDE (depending on the settings of your IDE).

Comment: I prefer branching strategy, with separate branches for frontend and backend. It's challenging to organize everything in one repository using only directories. For example, imagine the frontend team completes their tasks and wants to release a new version of the app, but the backend development is still ongoing. To release anything, we must ensure all directories are functioning, which I find cumbersome